# how to assign child element width to the parent element

Tags: javascript, css, svg

hi here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="500" height="100">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:green;stroke-width:3;stroke:gray">
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

when i inspect the element the svg occupied 500px because of i have set internally 500px to that  svg element. however i need, it should be occupied only child element width that is 300px.

Note : with out replacing svg width(500px) and without assign 300px to that element.

Comment: Just remove the fixed width for svg  ...

Comment: without removing width how to achieve?

Comment: could you use max-width for svg?

Comment: why without has no sense ..... https://jsfiddle.net/vgfvduhm/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a viewBox to show only the part of the drawing you want.

By default the aspect ratio will be preserved but I've overridden that below so that the width of 500 is obtained. I'm not sure what value of preserveAspectRatio would be most appropriate for you so you may need to experiment with different values.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="500" height="100" viewBox="0 0 300 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:green;stroke-width:3;stroke:gray"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```